# How to replace a caret with str_replace from stringr

Tags: r, str-replace, stringr

I have a code problem need some help(exclude specific string).

I found the `str_replace_all` to do the job.However,it works on other

characters like"/n", "/t" or "A","B","C",except the "^",I want to exclude

this sign but get a error message

> (Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : Missing closing bracket on a bracket expression.(U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET))

Thanks for your help!

```
code=c("^GSPC","^FTSE","000001.SS","^HSI","^FCHI","^KS11","^TWII","^GDAXI","^STI")
str_replace_all(code, "([^])", "")
```

Comment: Just escape: `str_replace_all(code, "\\^", "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to wrap with `fixed` and should be fine

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(code, fixed("^"), "")
#[1] "GSPC"      "FTSE"      "000001.SS" "HSI"       "FCHI"      "KS11"      "TWII"      "GDAXI"     "STI"
```

---

Also, as we are replacing with blank (`""`), an option is `str_remove`

```
str_remove(code, fixed("^"))
```

---

Regarding why the OP's code didn't, inside the square brackets, if we use `^`, it is not reading the literal character, instead the metacharacter in it looks for characters other than and here it is blank (`[^]`)

Comment: Thanks for your help